# grails - double data type truncated when saved (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy, double

I'm trying to save the exact amount in postgres. But after saving the value is change to 1 decimal.

Domain:

```
class Audit {

double a
double b
double c

}
```

Controller:

```
def save() {
..
new Audit(a: 1234.43, b: 7454.434, c: 64543.4346).save(flush: true)
..
}
```

Value in postgres:

```
a = 1234.4
b = 7454.4
c = 64543.4
```

How can I save the exact amount? Without truncating the value. Thank you

Comment: 1/ try to use `BigDecimal` data type instead of `double`. 2/ check the datatype in your database.

Comment: Knowing the column type in your database would be helpful.

Comment: @daggett BigDecimal data type does not work also. the culprit in my problem is the constraint scale set to 1.